# Connecting two servers via VPN

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

Usage: both client and our server will be sending API requests to each other. Basically our server will be 'consuming' their web-services AND we will need to expose certain API's to them.

Client setup: Has a server setup to which we can only connect via their secure server VPN.

Our Server: barebones linux.

TODO: configure server to connect to their VPN so that we are able to both consume and expose API's

Questions:

1. Do I need to configure the server just as a VPN client to connect to their VPN ?  Or will I have to also configure it as a VPN server as well?
2. I really don't have networking knowledge.. could there be something else that is required here to configure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that firewall rules permit, VPNs are bi-directional. By that, I mean that once the tunnel is up, systems on either side of the tunnel can initiate connections.